# PDF in CMYK or RGB color space

Tags: qgis, print-composer, pdf

In QGIS 2.14, in print composer I can save my project as a PDF file. There is no controls of the color space in which colors are specified in the output file. It will be very useful to have a choice of the color space: RGB or CMYK. 
Is it possible to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

QGIS uses the PDF output of the Qt toolkit which unfortunately has no way of setting the colour space. Indeed the Qt toolkit as a whole is 'colour space blind'. It would require a lot of work on the Qt toolkit to make this happen, and I know of no current efforts to do so.

A little more info is in [this "CMYK implementation in QGIS?" thread](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/CMYK-implementation-in-QGIS-td5178211.html) on the QGIS developer list.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this question, and while the above link no longer appears to be working, [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32754) is another discussion on the difficulties of implementing CMYK in QGIS on Github.