# Color separation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing, pdf, color

Is there a way to create color separated PDFs through QGIS's print composer?

I've also tried different PDF printers, but I haven't find any free option for it.

Comment: What do you mean by color separated pdfs? Could you edit your question to include some example images?

Comment: i think this might be a duplicate of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/186488/55203). I believe this is still the case, as of QGIS 2.18x / Qt 4 (the limitation is in Qt). If you want CMYK separations you might need to use Inkscape, GIMP, Scribus or similar to produce those using PDF/SVG or Image outputs from Composer.

Comment: Seems you could try doing it afterwards : https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/color-conversion-ink-management-acrobat.html or with Foxit : http://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-pdf-cmyk-printers-57070.html