# Exporting map as tif in CMYK colour space

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, color, publishing

I am getting my maps from QGIS ready for publication in a journal. The journal requires colour images to be tif format in the CMYK colour space. I understand how to save images as tif, but I cannot see a way to see whether I am saving them in the right colour space. Can anyone help me??

Comment: you will need a post process using gimp/ghostscript or photoshop to convert to cymk see https://askubuntu.com/questions/114858/how-to-convert-image-to-cmyk-in-gimp

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186488/in-qgis-print-composer-pdf-in-cmyk-or-rgb-color-space) to a similar question, QGIS doesn't have a way to set colorspace right now, due to its reliance on Qt libraries. A little more info is in [this thread](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/CMYK-implementation-in-QGIS-td5178211.html) on the QGIS developer list.

Answer (score 0):

try to translate geoTiff with Gdal_translate and
`PHOTOMETRIC=CMYK` option